# How do I set doubleClick function to call custom function in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, double-click

I have added a custom edit button control on the jqGrid navigator as follows:

```
jQuery("#grid").navButtonAdd('#pager',
    {  
     caption:"Edit", 
     buttonicon:"ui-icon-pencil", 
     onClickButton: editSelectedRow,
     position: "last", 
     title:"click to edit selected row", 
     cursor: "pointer",
     id: "edit-row"
    } 
  );
```

So that rather than use the default function: editGridRow, it uses my custom function editSelectedRow. However, I also want to add the doubleClick function to so that it calls editSelectedRow on doubleClick.

using the default editGridRow function works as such

```
ondblClickRow: function()
      {
       var rowid = jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
       jQuery(this).jqGrid('editGridRow', rowid);
      }
```

However, when I replace the default editGridRow function with my default function editSelectedRow as such,

```
ondblClickRow: function()
      {
       var rowid = jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
       jQuery(this).jqGrid('editSelectedRow', rowid);
      }
```

I get the following error within firebug:

```
uncaught exception: jqGrid - No such method: editSelectedRow
```

The function editSelectedRow however does exist and works with clicking the custom edit button. Please help, thanks.

**UPDATE**:
@Oleg: As requested here's the code defining method: editSelectedRow

```
function editSelectedRow(rowid)
{
    var rowid = jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
    if( rowid != null ) 
    {
        var dialogId = '#edit-form-dialog';
        var dialogTitle = 'Edit Customer';

        $(dialogId).load('/customer/edit/id/' + rowid, function () 
        {
            $(this).dialog(
            {
                modal: false,
                resizable: true,
                minWidth: 650,
                minHeight: 300,
                height: $(window).height() * 0.95,
                title: dialogTitle,
                buttons: 
                    {
                    "Save": function () 
                        {
                        var form = $('form', this);
                        $(form).submit();
                        $("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid");
                    },
                    "Cancel": function () 
                    {
                        $("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid");
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
          });

            LaunchEditForm(this);
        });
    }
    else
    {
        jQuery( "#dialogSelectRow" ).dialog();
    }
    return false;
 }
```

@Oleg: Thanks, you advised against using a custom method editSelectedRow in place of method editGridRow. The reason I am using this is that my forms are [Zend Forms](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.html) and I need all the bells and whistles of Zend Form to be available. The server generates this form and it's loaded into a dialog form. If there's a way to still achieve this without resorting to my editSelectedRow custom method, I'd be glad to learn it. Thanks.

Comment: Could you include the code which defines (implement) the `editSelectedRow` method? I suppose that you *don't replace* the `editGridRow` with another implementation `editSelectedRow`.

Comment: @Oleg: I have updated the question with the requested code.Thanks

Comment: I have seen that you never use [voting](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up). I suppose that you don't know how to use it and which value it has. You have right to vote up about 30 answers or question per day. The most important in voting is not that you give (for free) reputation points to other. The most important is that more voted questions and answers *will be found* by other users. So voting of helpful answers will help other to find the information. You can vote answers not only on your questions. So if you want to help other users you should use you right to vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You question is pure JavaScript question.

If you define the function `editSelectedRow` as

```
function editSelectedRow(rowid)
{
    ...
}
```

you can call it as `editSelectedRow(rowid)` and not as `jQuery(this).jqGrid('editSelectedRow', rowid);`.

Another problem is that you use `this` inside of he body of `editSelectedRow` function. It's not correct. You can define `editSelectedRow` function in a little another way

```
var editSelectedRow = function (rowid) {
    ...
};
```

In the case `editSelectedRow` will be able to bind `this` to any value. To do this you need use another form of invocation of the function. Inside of `ondblClickRow` it will be

```
ondblClickRow: function () {
    var rowid = jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
    editSelectedRow.call(this, rowid);
}
```

In the above example the first parameter of `call` is the value used as `this` inside of the function. We forward just the current `this` value forward to `editSelectedRow`. If we would use the form `editSelectedRow(rowid);` for the invocation of the function the value of `this` inside of function will be initialized to `window` object.

The usage of `editSelectedRow` inside of `navButtonAdd` can stay unchanged.

Comment: Thanks. I guessed it was a basic js issue I was dealing with but my js knowledge is currently limited. Thanks for your solution, it worked